# Custom permalink for one category

Tags: permalinks

I have the following permalink structure **/%category%/blog/%postname%**/.

I also have an archive at /blog which lists all blog posts.

I have one particular category for which I'd like the permalink structure to be  **/blog/%postname%/**

This is the code I've tried :

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {

$category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "hello" ) {
    $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/blog/'. $post->post_name 
.'/' ) );
}
return $permalink;
}
```

This first part works correctly and changes the url of the post with category 'hello' to https://example/blog/post-name - In the next part I'm trying to create a redirect for this url to the actual post.

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {

$feed_rules = array(

  '^blog/?' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
);
$wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
return $wp_rewrite->rules;;
}
```

This also works and redirects the url to https://example/blog/post-name
But! this url, instead of showing a single post - is showing my blog archive, so is rendering essentially the same as - https://example/blog/

My question - why is https://example/blog/post-name showing the same as https://example/blog/ rather than showing the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite rule doesn't capture anything. Change:

```
'^blog/?'
```

to add the capture group you reference with `$matches[1]` in your rule:

```
'^blog/([^/]+)/?'
```

visit the Settings > Permalinks page, which will flush rules, and your code should otherwise work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see a problem in your code you should know about, instead of using `rewrite_rules_array` which is final rewrite rules filter, or even something like `post_rewrite_rules` you using action `generate_rewrite_rules` to put your own rules accessing globally and changing `$wp_rewrite`. You better to use one of the suitable filters, like in this example.

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules ){
    $rule = [ '^blog/([^/]+)/?' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]' ];
    return array_merge( $rule, $rules);
});
```